# Laravel error: Declaration of Illuminate\Container\Container::get($id) must be compatible with Psr\Container\ContainerInterface::get(string $id)

Tags: php, laravel

Tengo un servidor web con **ISS** en un **Windows Server 2008 Enterprise Edition Service Pack 2** en el cual tiene **PHP 7.1.9**

lo primero que hice fue instalar la ultima versión de Laravel, el servidor me arroja un 505, explorando el `autoload.php` descubrí que llama un `platform_check.php` en el cual verifica la versión del PHP. Bueno luego Borre todos los archivos de la instalación del Laravel e instale la versión 5.8 en el cual solicita la versión 7.1.3 como mínimo. Vuelve a pasar lo mismo, el servidor me arroja un 505.

En internet encontré que se puede comentar el llamado al `platform_check.php`, cuando comento el archivo para que `composer` no haga la verificación de la versión

```
Fatal error: Declaration of Illuminate\Container\Container::get($id) must be compatible with Psr\Container\ContainerInterface::get(string $id) in C:\webApps\Replica\webLogin\apps\test-lara\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php on line 15
```

Como puedo hacer la instalación de Laravel sin comentar `platform_check.php`, para tener un sistema "prolijo"??

Y también. Como puedo solucionar el **`Fatal error`** que me arroja laravel?

Muchas gracias!

Answer (score -1):

Buen día,

Puede ser que el problema ocurra por la versión de `psr/container` que estes usando en PHP (V1.0.0 ó V1.1.0)

### Opción 1

Si fijas la versión de `psr/container` a V1.0.0 podría resolver el problema.

### Opción 2

Actualiza `composer` de la versión 1.0 a la version 2.0.

```
composer selfupdate --2
```

`composer` va a configurar la version de `psr\Container` a V1.0.0, si necesitas utilizar `composer` versión 1.0 puedes regresar de la versión 2.0 a la 1.0 con el siguiente comando:

```
composer self-update --1
```

Comment: Hacer eso me genero todo un entorno sin el `platform_check.php`, pero el **Fatal Error** sigue pasando.
Como hago para fijar el `psr/container` a V1.0.0, La opción 1